# How to Program 'Chance'?

Tags: c#, mysql

i have an idea of something but i don't have a clue how to do it :D
basically just like in the games for example, every 6 hours you can open a chest where you can grab some  item for free. Now i want to have a chest that the user can open every 6 hours, i have the items written in mysql server where every item gives experience points to the user. but how to do it?
lets say the database have 15 items, now every item have its chance value for example
`nothing = 75% of getting it`
`sword_1 = 15% of getting it`
`sword_2 = 30% of getting it`
any idea how to do it?

Comment: Tons: Look up "Weighted Distribution" and you will find plenty of solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. Define a range of % to get an item
   Example - sword_1 = 0-15%, sword_2 = 15-45%
   Note that the numbers above don't add up to 100%, so unless you really want return more than one time, sometimes.. the above ranges takes care of getting nothing.
   If you want multiple rewards on a roll, simply adjust the ranges accordingly.
2. Generate a **random number** between 0 and 100. For the items where generated number falls within the range, those are your rewards won for that round.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a numeric value to each of your items in the table, the percentage of getting it would be the difference between it and its next lowest number.

```
Nothing, 60  (60% chance)
sword_1, 70  (10% chance)
sword_2, 100 (30% chance)
```

Make sure that your max item is 100.

You can then do a select from that table with a random number:

```
SELECT * FROM ChestItems WHERE ChanceValue < FLOOR(RAND() * 100) ORDER BY ChanceValue DESC LIMIT 1;
```

There are several (and much better) ways you can do this. This is just a quick example.